# how to create google contact?

Tags: c#

i'm trying ti integrate with google gmail contacts i follow this example [Google Contacts API version 3.0](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/) i got this error Execution of request failed: https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full

```
Google.Contacts.Contact createdEntry = cr.Insert(feedUri, newEntry);
```

Inner expectation:

> {"The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request."}
>
> [Line 12, Column 127, element gd:im] Missing attribute: 'address'

the full code

```
using Google.Contacts;
using Google.GData.Contacts;
using Google.GData.Client;
using Google.GData.Extensions;



            RequestSettings settings = new RequestSettings("OVI2GoogleContacts", "my email", "pass");
        ContactsRequest cr = new ContactsRequest(settings);

        Google.Contacts.Contact newEntry = new Google.Contacts.Contact();

        // Set the contact's name.
        newEntry.Name = new Name()
            {
                FullName = "Elizabeth Bennet",
                GivenName = "Elizabeth",
                FamilyName = "Bennet",
            };
        newEntry.Content = "Notes";
         //Set the contact's e-mail addresses.
        newEntry.Emails.Add(new EMail()
            {
                Primary = true,
                Rel = ContactsRelationships.IsHome,
                Address = "liz<at>gmail.com"
            });
        newEntry.Emails.Add(new EMail()
            {
                Rel = ContactsRelationships.IsWork,
                Address = "liz<at>example.com"
            });
         //Set the contact's phone numbers.
        newEntry.Phonenumbers.Add(new PhoneNumber()
            {
                Primary = true,
                Rel = ContactsRelationships.IsWork,
                Value = "(206)555-1212",
            });
        newEntry.Phonenumbers.Add(new PhoneNumber()
            {
                Rel = ContactsRelationships.IsHome,
                Value = "(206)555-1213",
            });
        // Set the contact's IM information.
        newEntry.IMs.Add(new IMAddress()
            {
                Primary = true,
                Rel = ContactsRelationships.IsHome,
                Protocol = ContactsProtocols.IsGoogleTalk,
            });
        // Set the contact's postal address.
        newEntry.PostalAddresses.Add(new StructuredPostalAddress()
            {
                Rel = ContactsRelationships.IsWork,
                Primary = true,
                Street = "1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy",
                City = "Mountain View",
                Region = "CA",
                Postcode = "94043",
                Country = "United States",
                FormattedAddress = "1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy Mountain View",
            });
        // Insert the contact.
        Uri feedUri = new Uri(ContactsQuery.CreateContactsUri("default"));
        Google.Contacts.Contact createdEntry = cr.Insert(feedUri, newEntry); // here the error
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Google's own sample code appears to be invalid.  According to the documentation [Google Data type/kind gd:im requires the property address to be populated](https://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/2.0/elements#gdIm).

> @address
>
> @label?
>
> @rel?
>
> @protocol?
>
> @primary?

Conventions:

> elementName    Required element
>
> elementName **?**  Optional element
>
> elementName *****  Optional element, multiple instances allowed

You'll need to update a part of the code like:

```
newEntry.IMs.Add(new IMAddress()
{
  Address = "email@dot.com",  // untested
  Primary = true,
  Rel = ContactsRelationships.IsHome,
  Protocol = ContactsProtocols.IsGoogleTalk,
});
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is while adding IM to the contact entry as suggested by Erik above...
In the google api example, they have missed mentioning the IM Address

just add ***Address = "liz@gmail.com",*** to folllowing

```
    // Set the contact's IM information.
    newEntry.IMs.Add(new IMAddress()
        {
            Primary = true,
            Rel = ContactsRelationships.IsHome,
            Protocol = ContactsProtocols.IsGoogleTalk,
            **Address = "liz@gmail.com",**
        });
```