# Contact creation error using python-gdata API

Tags: python, gdata-api, google-shared-contacts

I have a question regarding contact creation using the python Google data API.
I am trying the example for contact creation with python, exactly like it is in the documentation page (https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#creating_contacts)

So, i created the client as following:

```
email='<my gmail uid>'
password='<my gmail pwd>'
gd_client = gdata.contacts.client.ContactsClient(source='GoogleInc-ContactsPythonSample-1')
try:
    gd_client.ClientLogin(email, password, gd_client.source)
except gdata.client.BadAuthentication:
    print 'Invalid user credentials given.'
    gd_client = None
```

Then i executed the function using:

```
create_contact(gd_client)
```

What i get from this call is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<ipython console>", line 23, in create_contact
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'PostCode'
```

So I want to ask whether i am doing something wrong, whether this is a known bug, or whether the documentation is simply outdated.
Thanks.

p.s. a small comment, i think a better wrapping of the Google data API in the python library could be useful. I spent significant time in finding, within the API implementation, what fields should be set (directly!) and what classes should be used to assign them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it seems that i can answer my question, which is partly a duplicate of

[how to create google contact?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10364606/how-to-create-google-contact)

It turns out that the sample code in the documentation is invalid (thanks, Google)
PostCode should be Postcode, and the instant messaging address is also incorrect.

Removing that, it completes successfully