# How to add my local contact to gmail account?

Tags: c#, gdata, gmail-api, google-contacts-api

I have application related to gmail account. I want to add my local database contact to gmail account. I have referred this link : [how to create google contact?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10364606/how-to-create-google-contact) 
Is this possible? Please suggest me way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not create contacts with the `gmail-api`, but the [Contacts API: Creating Contacts](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#creating_contacts) will do what you are looking for:

```
public static Contact CreateContact(ContactsRequest cr)
{
  Contact newEntry = new Contact();
  // Set the contact's name.
  newEntry.Name = new Name()
      {
        FullName = "Elizabeth Bennet",
        GivenName = "Elizabeth",
        FamilyName = "Bennet",
      };
  newEntry.Content = "Notes";
  // Set the contact's e-mail addresses.
  newEntry.Emails.Add(new EMail()
      {
        Primary = true,
        Rel = ContactsRelationships.IsHome,
        Address = "liz@gmail.com"
      });
  newEntry.Emails.Add(new EMail()
      {
        Rel = ContactsRelationships.IsWork,
        Address = "liz@example.com"
      });
  // Set the contact's phone numbers.
  newEntry.Phonenumbers.Add(new PhoneNumber()
      {
        Primary = true,
        Rel = ContactsRelationships.IsWork,
        Value = "(206)555-1212",
      });
  newEntry.Phonenumbers.Add(new PhoneNumber()
      {
        Rel = ContactsRelationships.IsHome,
        Value = "(206)555-1213",
      });
  // Set the contact's IM information.
  newEntry.IMs.Add(new IMAddress()
      {
        Primary = true,
        Rel = ContactsRelationships.IsHome,
        Protocol = ContactsProtocols.IsGoogleTalk,
      });
  // Set the contact's postal address.
  newEntry.PostalAddresses.Add(new StructuredPostalAddress()
      {
        Rel = ContactsRelationships.IsWork,
        Primary = true,
        Street = "1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy",
        City ="Mountain View",
        Region = "CA",
        Postcode = "94043",
        Country = "United States",
        FormattedAddress = "1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy Mountain View",
      });
  // Insert the contact.
  Uri feedUri = new Uri(ContactsQuery.CreateContactsUri("default"));
  Contact createdEntry = cr.Insert(feedUri, newEntry);
  Console.WriteLine("Contact's ID: " + createdEntry.Id)
  return createdEntry;
}
```

Comment: @Tholle thank you. This create new contact in gmail account but it doesn't show in contact list. I must open "Elizabeth Bennet" from search and then I must edit-save the contact to get it in the contact list.